# TypeError: logWarnFn is not a function - jest - nodejs

Tags: node.js, jestjs, internationalization, node-modules, ts-jest

Getting this error when I try to run my jest test cases on my nodejs server

```
TypeError: logWarnFn is not a function

      18 |     });
      19 |     if (!user) {
    > 20 |       throw new createHttpError.BadRequest(i18n.__("user_not_exist"));
         |                                                 ^
      21 |     }
```

I am using i18n module for translation. Not sure why jest is not picking it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking the i18n module seems to solve this issue.

```
jest.mock("i18n")
```

Comment: What file did you add this to?

Comment: @YTG the file which is throwing this error